# Motion detection by eliminating constant movements

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, motion-detection

I am trying to implement a motion detection in OpenCV C++. I tried various methods like MOG, Optical flow which work fine but is there a way we can eliminate constant movements in the scene like a constant fan motion etc ? I have opencv `accumuateWeighted()` in mind but not sure if it works. Is there any better way we can do it ?

Comment: Well, it depends how you define movement? for example, if you have a binary representation of your image with white where there is movement and black where there is not, you can average the frames (the binary ones, using floats or doubles). Then you can threshold this averaged image to your liking, like if you used 200 frames, if it is more than 0.5 in the pixel then it moved in more than 100 frames... or 0.75 in more than 150.. The closer to 1 (if the binary image had 1 in the movement areas) the more it moved. Then you can mask this areas in your images. This works if it is in the same place

Comment: What do you mean by constant movements- does it mean object with only rotational or periodic motion but no translation over a certain period of time?

Comment: @flamelite constants movements like localized motions as in leaves, fans etc

Comment: @api55 thanks for the suggestion. i'll see that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not got full robust solution and also i don't have any experience with video processing but i would put my idea whatever till now i have got in to this problem:

First consider a few pairs of consecutive image frames from the video and convert them to gray scale for more robust comparison.

Raster scan the image pairs and find the difference of image pairs by comparing corresponding pairs.
The resultant image will give the pixel location where there is a change in image to image in a pair, cluster these pixels locations and make a bounding box over them. So that this bounding box region will mark an object which is translating/rotation.

Now as we have applied the above image difference operation over several pairs. We will have rotating/translating bounding box in each image pair difference.
Now check in each resultant image difference with pixels having bounding box over them.

Compare bounding box central location in a difference image with other difference images. If bounding box with a very slight variation in its central location exists across all difference images then object contained in that bounding box will be having rotational motion like Fan,leaves and remaining bounding boxes will represent the actual translating objects in the video.